# Samsung Galaxy S6 touchscreen sensitivity

Tags: samsung, touchscreen, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Is there a way to adjust the touchscreen sensitivity on the Samsung Galaxy S6? I feel like I am going to damage the screen with how hard I have to press to accomplish anything. Typing takes forever and is frustrating. TIA.

Comment: It's likely that this is purely controlled by hardware/firmware, so no settings you can change, but upgrading your ROM might help.  What is your Android version?

Comment: I checked my phone settings and it says that the Android version is 5.1.1, it doesn't give a name like kitkat, lollipop, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change it, but if you have to press that hard, it may be defective.